# drag and drop upload in IE

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload, internet-explorer-9

does anyone know of any way of allowing people to upload files to the server from the desktop using drag and drop and IE. It's fine if it works only in IE9. I've found several solutions that only work with the other browser. However, internally we use IE here :-(. I would even settle for flash but it seems that swfupload doesn't support drag and drop.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

As far as I understand ie9 doesnt support the File api, but only drag and drop. ie 10 will possibly support the File api.

http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/html5-drag-and-drop-and-file-api-tutorial/

although you may be able to work around this now - try:
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload
http://aquantum-demo.appspot.com/file-upload

Comment: ha.. I posted the same link as you before my page was refreshed - nice : )

Comment: the aquantum demo is the one that I have implemented. It degrades under IE to just a regular open file dialog box. It doesn't allow drag and drop onto it. DND is key for me.

Answer (score 2):

HTML5 provides a drag & drop API as well as [File API](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/).

[http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/html5-drag-and-drop-and-file-api-tutorial](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/html5-drag-and-drop-and-file-api-tutorial/) and http://html5demos.com/file-api

Unfortunately IE9 doesn't support the File API and it's unclear how much support will be available in IE10.

Comment: ya but IE doesnt support the File API yet, no?

Comment: Ah, @Adam is correct, unfortunately there's no File API support in IE9.

Comment: yup I've been down that path already. I got it implemented using jquery file upload plugin for all other browsers.